# CUDA model - what is warp size?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

What's the relationship between maximum work group size and warp size? Let’s say my device has 240 CUDA streaming processors (SP) and returns the following information -

CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS: 30

CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES: 512 / 512 / 64

CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE: 512

CL_NV_DEVICE_WARP_SIZE: 32

This means it has eight SPs per streaming multiprocessor (that is, compute unit). Now how is warp size = 32 related to these numbers?

Answer (score 132):

**Direct Answer:**  Warp size is the number of threads in a warp, which is a sub-division used in the hardware implementation to coalesce memory access and instruction dispatch.

**Suggested Reading:**

As @Matias mentioned, I'd go read the [CUDA C Best Practices Guide](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/cuda_3_2_toolkit_rc.html) (you'll have to scroll to the bottom where it's listed). It might help for you to stare at the table in Appendix G.1 on page 164.

**Explanation:**

CUDA is language which provides parallelism at two levels. You have threads and you have blocks of threads. This is most evident when you execute a kernel; you need to specify the size of each thread block and the number of thread blocks in between the <<< >>> which precede the kernel parameters.

What CUDA doesn't tell you is things are actually happening at four levels, not two. In the background, your block of threads is actually divided into sub-blocks called "warps". Here's a brief metaphor to help explain what's really going on:

**Brief Metaphor:**

Pretend you're an educator/researcher/politician who's interested in the current mathematical ability of high school seniors. Your plan is to give a test to 10,240 students, but you can't just put them all in a football stadium or something and give them the test. It is easiest to subdivide (parallelize) your data collection -- so you go to 20 different high school and ask that 512 of their seniors each take the math test.

*The number of high schools, 20, is analagous to the number of "blocks" / "number of blocks of threads". The number of seniors, 512, is analagous to the number of threads in each block aka "threads per block".*

You collect your data and that is all you care about. What you didn't know (and didn't *really* care about) is that each school is actually subdivided into classrooms. So your 512 seniors are actually divided into 16 groups of 32. And further, none of these schools really has the resources required -- each classroom only has sixteen calculators. Hence, at any one time only half of each classroom can take your math test.

*The number of seniors, 512, represents the number of threads per block requested when launching a CUDA Kernel. The implementation hardware may further divide this into 16 sequential blocks of 32 threads to process the full number of requested threads, which is 512. The number 32 is the warp size, but this may vary on different hardware generations.*

I could go on to stretch silly rules like only eight classrooms in any one school can take the test at one time because they only have eight teachers.  You can't sample more than 30 schools simultaneously because you only have 30 proctors...

**Back to your question:**

Using the metaphor, your program wants to compute results as fast as possible (you want to collect math tests). You issue a kernel with a certain number of blocks (schools) each of which has a certain number of threads (students). You can only have so many blocks running at one time (collecting your survey responses requires one proctor per school). In CUDA, thread blocks run on a streaming multiprocessor (SM). The variable: `CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS` tells you how many SMs, **30**, a specific card has. This varies drastically based on the hardware -- check out the table in Appendix A of the [CUDA C Best Practices Guide](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/cuda_3_2_toolkit_rc.html). Note that each SM can run only eight blocks simultaneously regardless of the compute capability (1.X or 2.X).

Thread blocks have maximum dimensions: `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_SIZES`. Think of laying out your threads in a grid; you can't have a row with more than **512** threads. You can't have a column with more than **512** threads. And you can't stack more than **64** threads high. Next, there is a maximum: `CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE` number of threads, **512**, that can be grouped together in a block. So your thread blocks' dimensions could be:

512 x 1 x 1

1 x 512 x 1

4 x 2 x 64

64 x 8 x 1

etc...

Note that as of Compute Capability 2.X, your blocks can have at most 1024 threads. Lastly, the variable `CL_NV_DEVICE_WARP_SIZE` specifies the warp size, **32** (number of students per classroom). In Compute Capability 1.X devices, memory transfers and instruction dispatch occur at the **Half-Warp** granularity (you only have 16 calculators per classroom). In Compute Capability 2.0, memory transfers are grouped by **Warp**, so 32 fetches simultaneously, but instruction dispatch is still only grouped by **Half-Warp**. For Compute Capability 2.1, both memory transfers *and* instruction dispatch occur by **Warp**, 32 threads. ***These things can and will change in future hardware.***

So, my word! Let's get to the point:

**In Summary:**

I have described the nuances of warp/thread layout and other such stuff, but here are a couple of things to keep in mind. First, your memory access should be "groupable" in sets of 16 or 32. So keep the X dimension of your blocks a multiple of 32. Second, **and most important** to get the most from a specific gpu, you need to maximize occupancy. Don't have 5 blocks of 512 threads. And don't have 1,000 blocks of 10 threads. I would **strongly** recommend checking out the [Excel-based spreadsheet](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-occupancy-calculator/CUDA_Occupancy_Calculator.xls) (works in [OpenOffice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice.org) too?? I think??) which will tell you what the GPU occupancy will be for a specific kernel call (thread layout **and** shared memory requirements). I hope this explanation helps!

Comment: Very nice answer and metaphor. Just want to add that AMD has similar notion called Wavefront, and is currently 64 threads/wavefront.

Comment: Huh.  I didn't know that.  I haven't spent much time looking at the AMD offerings.  Do you have an idea if this will change dramatically with the Fusion offerings?

Comment: Future fusion parts are all based on the Evergreen architecture, so wavefront should stay 64 threads: http://www.highperformancegraphics.org/media/Hot3D/HPG2010_Hot3D_AMD.pdf

Comment: @M.Tibbits can you tell which excel sheet you referring to?

Comment: [This one](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/CUDA_Occupancy_calculator.xls)

Comment: @M.Tibbits , you just write "Note that each SM can run can only work on eight **blocks** simultaneouly regardless of the compute capability (1.X or 2.X).", but I just guess you mean each SM can only allow eight **warps** work simultaneously, right?

Comment: @YanAn: M.Tibbits is correct. Please see [Nvidia's Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications__technical-specifications-per-compute-capability) for more info.

Maximum number of resident blocks per multiprocessor = 8 for CC 2.X, CC 1.X is unlisted as of now.

Comment: Yes, @Kelsius, you are right, I just misunderstanding that.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, I disagree with your comment "Don't have 5 blocks of 512 threads". If each kernel is small enough to maximize occupancy, there is no reason not to saturate the compute device by using the largest possible block size. They may be further split down by the CUDA device, and it may be the case that 512 threads do not run concurrently, but as far as I am presently aware there is no reason not to do this unless the shared memory requirements are too high. Perhaps I misunderstood something? Someone with more experience than myself can perhaps comment on this?

Comment: Also I liked your example with the school but found it a bit confusing to read as I prefer to think about the actual structure of the hardware rather than an analogy, however I understand why others may find the analogy easier to understand. I added some comments in italic to give some further explanation as to how the two ways of thinking are related. Could you please check that my explanations are correct? In particular the comment about the warp size being "32". Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The warp size is the number of threads that a multiprocessor executes concurrently. An NVIDIA multiprocessor can execute several threads from the same block at the same time, using hardware multithreading.

It's important to consider the warp size, since all memory accesses are coalesced into multiples of the warp size (32 bytes, 64 bytes, 128 bytes), and this improves performance.

The [CUDA C Best Practices Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_1/toolkit/docs/NVIDIA_CUDA_C_BestPracticesGuide_3.1.pdf) contains all the technical information about these kind of optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer is brief: In Nvidia, BLOCKs composed by THREADs are set by programmer, and WARP is 32 (consists of 32 threads), which is the minimum unit being executed by compute unit at the same time.
In AMD, WARP is called WAVEFRONT ("wave").

In OpenCL, the WORKGROUPs means BLOCKs in CUDA, what's more, the WORKITEMs means THREADs in CUDA.

Comment: This is an informative answer at some level; however, it doesn't really tell us about warps and how to factor them in when writing code.

As Richard Feynmann once said, "Knowing the name of something doesn't mean you understand it." To teach well, you should explain how something operates or is used.